# Can't detect if developer options are enabled in API 25?

Tags: java, android

In the Android Studio emulator (API 25 only), I can't detect if developer options are enabled.

This code always returns true, even if developer options *are not* enabled... How can I fix this?

```
int developerOptions = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
```

I tried `Settings.Global.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);` but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's should be done with next line for Devices <16:

```
int result = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0);
```

For other old devices >16 (*it's your case, and that's why it fails*)

```
int result = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
```

As an alternative. You should 1. try on real devices, because different goldfish status of emulator might effect you response.

**UPDATE.**

And 2. Call `Activity` for developer option. If it's failed it's should be disabled. When it is exist, you don't need to open it, and you can close immediately. For ex.

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS), 8080);
    // You might also post a delay for finishing activity. 
    finishActivity(8080);

    // Activity exist behavior
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Disabled Developer options
}
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work with API 25 on the Android Studio emulator, please try it out

Comment: @Bandy try alternative solution, and try without emulator too. This is how it works perfectly locally.

Comment: the 2nd solution doesn't work well with huawei devices, i've tried it already :/

Comment: @Bandy you can try last one too.

Comment: But the last one opens a new activity. I don't want to open a new activity, I just want to check

Comment: @Bandy Updated information without starting activity.

Comment: Your last solution doesn't work. It simply doesn't detect if developer options are enabled or not. Because the catch statement is never called even if developer options are disabled on my phone.